# PrimaryKey, ForeignKey e Unique Com JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, aplicação-web

Tenho a Seguinte situação:

1. Entidade Aluno (id e demais)
2. Entidade Avaliação (id e demais)
3. Entidade NotaAvaliacaoAluno (avaliacaoId, alunoId)

Desejo transformar os atributos avaliacaoId, alunoId que possuem relações com as entidades 1 e 2 em PrimaryKey e que sejam Unique.

Qual a melhor maneira para este mapeamento?

Já verifiquei algumas formas mas fique em dúvida de como realmente utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

1- Primeiro você precisa mapear a entidade *Aluno*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Aluno") // Eu sempre informo o 'name', mania minha
public class Aluno implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private java.lang.Long id; 

  // Demais campos...
}
```

2 - Mapear Entidade *Avaliacao*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Avaliacao")
public class Avaliacao implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private java.lang.Long id; 

  // Demais campos...
}
```

3 - Mapear a entidade *NotaAvaliacao*

Antes de postar o exemplo, nem sempre é necessário mapear essas many-to-many. Eu resolvi mapea-la pelo fato dela ter informações (Que acredito ser a nota do aluno).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NotaAvaliacaoAluno")
public class NotaAvaliacaoAluno implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn( name = "avaliacaoId", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Avaliacao avaliacao; 

  @Id
  @Column(name = "alunoId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "alunoId", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Aluno aluno; 

  // Demais campos...
}
```

4 - Agora voltamos para a classe aluno e incluimos

```
 @OneToMany(fetch=fetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="aluno")
 private List<NotaAvaliacaoAluno> notasValiacaoAlunoList;
```

Pronto.

P.S.: Como não conheço seu modelo acredito que o mais adequado e analisar minha resposta, entender o que sugeri e adaptar ao seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Em todos os casos você precisará de uma chave composta (já que do lado do banco a PK é composta o JPA deve manter esse modelo).

Isso pode ser feito de duas maneiras:

1. Entidade de ID + `@IdClass`

   ```
   public class NotaAvaliacaoAlunoPK implements Serializable { 
       private Integer idAluno;
       private Integer idAvaliacao;
       // Outros campos da PK se existirem

       // Getters & setters, equals e hashCode
   }

   @Entity 
   @IdClass(value=NotaAvaliacaoAlunoPK.class)
   public class NotaAvaliacaoAluno implements Serializable { 
       @Id @Column(name="ID_ALUNO")
       private Integer idAluno;
       @Id @Column(name="ID_AVALIACAO")
       private Integer idAvaliacao;
       // Outros campos da PK se existirem
       @Column
       private String outroCampoQualquer;

       // Getters & setters
   }
   ```
2. Múltiplas colunas de IDs + `@EmbeddedId`

   ```
   @Embeddable
   public class NotaAvaliacaoAlunoPK implements Serializable { 
       @Column(name="ID_ALUNO")
       private Integer idAluno;
       @Column(name="ID_AVALIACAO")
       private Integer idAvaliacao;

       // Getters & setters, equals e hashCode
   }

   @Entity 
   public class NotaAvaliacaoAluno implements Serializable { 
       @EmbeddedId
       private NotaAvaliacaoAlunoPK id;
       @Column
       private String outroCampoQualquer;
   }
   ```

A segunda decisão é saber quem *manda* na Primary Key, se são os campos da PK diretamente ou se são os relacionamentos com `Aluno` e `Avaliacao`.

1. Se são os campos da *primary key*, faça com que os relacionamentos não atualizem o banco:

   ```
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="ID_ALUNO", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Aluno aluno;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="ID_AVALIACAO", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Avaliacao avaliacao;
   ```
2. Se são os relacionamentos, faça com que os campos da PK não atualizem o banco e que as entidades dos relacionamentos façam (através de `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`):

   ```
   @Column(name="ID_ALUNO", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Integer idAluno;
   @Column(name="ID_AVALIACAO", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Integer idAvaliacao;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID_ALUNO")
   private Aluno aluno;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID_AVALIACAO")
   private Avaliacao avaliacao;
   ```

Veja que nem entrei no mérito de [*Element Collections*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) para não complicar ainda mais o tópico, porém o uso de coleções pode ser uma boa ideia caso os valores de nota avaliação não façam sentido fora do contexto do objeto pai.

Sobre a maneira "mais correta" de modelar um problema, não existe uma resposta fácil. Pode ser que na sua aplicação faça mais sentido manipular os ids diretamente, talvez faça mais sentido construir um objeto de ID. Talvez faça mais sentido lidar com os valores da PK diretamente (inserindo ids de alunos e avaliações), talvez o oposto faça sentido (buscar o objeto Aluno e o objeto Avaliação inteiros do banco e setar os relacionamentos).

E há ainda quem prefira apelar para um bom e velho mapa:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="aluno")
@MapKeyColumn(name="ID_AVALIACAO")
private Map<Integer, NotaAvaliacao> notas;
```